# Is there an Ansible/Jinja2 subgroup variables unique filter?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

We are using Ansible to generate some iptables rules from a Jinja2 template. The hosts are in nested groups, and their subnets are stored as variables in the child group variables within the inventory file like this:

```
[parent_group]
[parent_group:children]
child_group1
    [child_group1]
    FQDN1
    FQDN2
    [child_group1:vars]
    subnet=10.0.0.0/24
```

We have many child groups, each with their own subnet/mask for their respective host groups. Most of the Ansible/Jinja2 documentation points to referencing the group variables by using a for-loop to iterate over their member hosts, which would result in duplicate lines in our template file. What is the best way to grab the child_group vars of parent_group only once? Is there a way to filter for unique values in a Jinja2 for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an expression to get a list of unique subnets for hosts in `parent_group`:

```
{{ groups['parent_group'] | map('extract',hostvars,'subnet') | list | unique }}
```

This technique of value extraction is described [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers).

Answer (score 0):

After some fumbling around with Jinja2 expressions, I was able to come up with the following template to create rules based on child group variables without duplicates:

```
{% set subnets = [] %}
{% for host in groups['parent_group'] %}
{% if hostvars[host].subnet not in subnets %}
-A INPUT -s {{hostvars[host].subnet}} -j ACCEPT {{subnets.append(hostvars[host].subnet)}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It feels rather clunky to me, so if anyone knows a better way, I would really appreciate it.